# Where does Feeds cache the source and how do I disable this cache feature?

Tags: feeds

I've found out that Feeds caches the sources. Even when I change the content of the source, emptying the imported items and reimport, it imports the old items.

Where does Feeds store this cache and how do I disable this cache feature?

I need to disable this caching feature because I am dealing with sources which change often.

Comment: Which drupal/feeds version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I've posted this issue on Drupal before. Basically it's a problem that they are working on.

http://drupal.org/node/1156062